# Keyboard shortcuts not persisting

Tags: shell-script, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce4-terminal

I have a custom script that I sometimes run as an alternative to the main terminal. The script has functioned fine for just under three years, and I always test it after making changes. It still works fine.

I'm currently logged in as root after a recent screwup unrelated to the script caused me to have to reinstall my whole system. It's the same distro as before, so nothing's changed there. I've run an update, @nd the script itself still functions fine.

The problem lies in my keyboard shortcuts.
As stated, I'm logged in as root. I'm running XFCE4 as my SM/WM.
In my keyboard settings, I've tried setting Super+T as my keyboard shortcut for the command "bash /root/myscriptname". However, the shortcut will not work, despite that same command functioning perfectly fine in a standard terminal.

I've tried putting "sudo" at the beginning of the command, also no luck.

I've also tried setting it to such things as "xfce4-terminal --command="bash /root/myscript", and also switching it out for gnome-terminal, etc, again also trying sudo.

The shortcut is listed right there if I close and re-open the shortcuts menu.

I've tried logging out, turning off and on again, etc, all to no avail.

Can anyone offer any advice, other than "don't use root" (I know, it's just until I've got things set up properly again...)?

Thank you :)

EDIT: The shortcut persistently shows as "super+t", even after closing and opening the window, logging out and in again, etc. HOWEVER, for some reason it is still activating from the old shortcut of "ctrl+alt+t". Seems very strange.

Comment: Where is the script located? Maybe it is in your users `~/.config` and thus not in  `/root`. It sounds as if you assume a user setting for your account to be present for root, too.

Comment: The script is in /root.

Comment: I've tried assigning the shortcut to a normal command, "xfce4-terminal", which is installed, and again runs as a command in terminal but doesn't work for super+t

Comment: I rolled back your recent edit, adding a solution to the question text. If you have a solution, consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer